# Lets Encrypt 403 - The client lacks sufficient authorization. Drupal 7 Site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

When trying to generate the LetsEncript cert I am getting the following 403.

> [ec2-user@myip html]$ /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto certonly
>   --webroot -w /var/www/html -d example.com -d www.example.com  --config /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini --agree-tos Checking for new version... Requesting root privileges to run letsencrypt...    sudo
>   /home/ec2-user/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt certonly
>   --webroot -w /var/www/html/myroot -d example.com -d www.example.com --config /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini --agree-tos
>   Version: 1.1-20080819 Version: 1.1-20080819 Failed authorization
>   procedure. mydomain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The
>   client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from
>   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/IDug1d_rT8rZNPQQfdsgfdgsdfBKRJaHMTa3kulh4HnQ
>   [52.30.98.10]: 403
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: mydomain.com    Type:   unauthorized    Detail: Invalid
>   response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-
>   challenge/IDug1d_rT8rZNPQQkjsdgfdgdfggdfajhsTa3kulh4HnQ
>   [52.30.98.101]: 403
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to Configure Let’s Encrypt on Drupal

To make your Drupal site work with Let’s Encrypt, below are the changes require in the htaccess file.

This line:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
```

Swapped by this line:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
```

And, this line:

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

Swapped by this line:

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]
```

Source:
https://support.cloudways.com/configure-drupal-lets-encrypt/

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Drupal's .htaccess file (rightly so) was not allowing the hidden file to be accessed. I temporarily renamed the .htaccess file to .temphtaccess and the authorisation worked.

/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/myroot -d example.com -d www.example.com  --config /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini --agree-tos
Checking for new version...
Requesting root privileges to run letsencrypt...
   sudo /home/ec2-user/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/myroot -d example.com -d www.example.com --config /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini --agree-tos
Version: 1.1-20080819
Version: 1.1-20080819

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem. Your cert will
   expire on 2016-07-17. To obtain a new version of the certificate in
   the future, simply run Let's Encrypt again.
 - If you like Let's Encrypt, please consider supporting our work by:

Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le

Comment: this renaming strategy will not help you when renewal time comes around, unless you always feel like doig it manually..